# Why are CTE faster than joins

Tags: sql, join, common-table-expression, with-statement

I have read that the performance of the `With` statement is in some cases greatly better than joins. However, when joining on varchars (I avoid that normally), I saw a great improvement in speed when I replaced a join with a `With`

For example, I have three tables that I want to join: `Customer, CustomerNickname, Address` (not a real example but will do for the question)

I would normally use the following query to retrieve data:

```
select * from customer c
inner join address a on c.addressid = a.id
left join CustomerNickname cn on cn.originalname = c.name --name and original name are varchars
```

If those tables have a lot of data, performance will be really bad because of the varchar join. However, if I replace the query with:

```
  with Nicknames as (
         select * from CustomerNickname
   )
    select * from customer c
    inner join address a on c.addressid = a.id
    left join Nicknames cn on cn.originalname = c.name
```

performance will greatly improve. In my example (I didn't add it here because it is too much tables) the query went from a minute to a second. Furthermore, I noticed in the execution plan of the original query that there is a `SORT` operator with cost of 95%. Where does this come from.

So, two questions:

- Why is With so much faster?
- Where does the `SORT` operator come from in the execution plan.

Comment: Show the execution plans for both, plus the IO STATISTICs and then it's much easier to tell you why one is faster than the other or similar. Because often it comes down to how the optimizer can reduce data to move between operations.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, unfortunately I can't include this because I don't have access to the query/database anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The query is joining a varchar to varchar therefore will do a scan operation. this is quite expensive even with indexes.
[Why does Mysql use a full table scan for table A when joining another table B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096158/why-does-mysql-use-a-full-table-scan-for-table-a-when-joining-another-table-b)
I suspect the CTE is keeping a dynaset in RAM on the server, and is therefore much faster.
(the entire set of results for the CTE is loaded from disk to RAM unsorted).