# Why does Mysql use a full table scan for table A when joining another table B?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a table A and a table B. I am selecting information from table A where I need only the information from table A where tabel B joins table A. I have indexes on columns that are joint and on the WHERE clause.

This is the select code:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA

INNER JOIN tableB AS tableB
ON tableB.id = tableA.id
AND tableB.type = 'car'
```

When I use explain I can see that mysql is using a full table scan for all the rows in tableA. Further it properly uses the index to join tableB.

So what Mysql seems to be doing is scan all the rows in talbeA to see if there is a match with tableB. However as I have indexes on id of both tables I don't expect a tablescan. As my table has 50.000 rows this query is taking a few seconds (which is really too long for my application).

This is the explain:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tableA      ALL     tableA.id       NULL    NULL    49898   
1   SIMPLE  tableB      eq_ref  tableB.type     tableB.type 4   1       Use WHere
```

**My question:** How can I optimize this query and indexes such that Mysql directly selects those rows from tableA that have a match with tableB without scanning all rows in talbeA?

Comment: Could you add the explain result to the question?

Comment: But I you do a "select * from tableA", you also have a fullscan because you don't put any where condition to restrict the content of tableA.

Comment: @NoDataFound That is correct, but the data I want from table A is restricted by where tableA has a match. So I only want that information from tableA whereever there is a match with tableB. So the WHERE condition would be wherever tableB is joined.

Comment: @BastiaanWW Is the explain really for the whole join and not just `SELECT * FROM tableA`? It should at least mention `tableB` a'la the execution plan [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e25d/2).

Comment: is Table.id a primary/unique key?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That's correct, I didn't think it really matterd as it is working the right way, 1 row scanned only. I updated explain though

Comment: @BastiaanWW Could you add details on how the index on tablea.id is created?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It is a BTREE index created like this: ALTER TABLE `tableA` ADD INDEX (`id`).

Comment: @rontornambe It is not the primary/unique id, the table has a unique and primary key, but is not used in this query

Comment: @BastiaanWW Odd, doing that I get a plan similar to [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28f10/1).

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I see, what you did is the same plan as what I need. After some search I discovered that there is a minimum of 5% of the total number of rows required to make use of an index efficient. As I was generating random input often more than 5% of the rows was required. Tweaking my query for this resulted into suddenly using the index as required. Thanks for your help and support!

Answer (score 0):

This is the maximum optimization you can get for a JOIN query 
refer her for more details 
https://cryptkcoding.com/blog/2012/04/06/how-to-optimize-mysql-join-queries-through-indexing/